# Is there a difference between Arrays.fill and actual fill

Tags: java, arrays

This question might appear trivial, but I am unable to find a solution to this problem for a few days.

Snippet 1 :

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = new Bucket();
}
```

Snippet 2 :

```
Arrays.fill(arr, new Bucket());
```

Code with snippet 1 is executing as expected, but code that includes snippet 2 is not passing all the test cases.

I am expecting both the statements to do the same work internally. But the test cases show it is not. Any help to clarify this will be very helpful.

Comment: Test Cases include unsorted integer arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.fill()` uses the same object all time:

```
public static void fill(Object[] a, Object val) {
    for (int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++)
        a[i] = val;
}
```

So entire array becomes filled with a single instance created once by `new Bucket()`

Answer (score 5):

Think about what they do: in the loop you create a new object *on every iteration*. In the second you create *one object* and fill the array with it. They are totally different.

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

> Assigns the specified Object reference to each element of the specified array of Objects.

Answer (score 0):

> I am expecting both the statements to do the same work internally.

Snippet 2 is only creating one `Bucket`, and adding the same instance to every slot. So they are not the same, in Java 8+ you could use a lambda and something like

```
IntStream.range(0, arr.length).forEach(x -> arr[x] = new Bucket());
```

to fill the `Bucket[] arr`.